How to set headers for assets within _app/immutable/workers?
I've successfully built a SvelteKit app, but when I try to run npm rum preview, I see that the following asset was unable to be loaded:
http://localhost:4173/_app/immutable/workers/shout.wasm.worker-fuz9AyH7.js.
The browser console says:
Because your site has the Cross-Origin Embedder Policy (COEP) enabled, each embedded iframe must also specify this policy. This behavior protects private data from being exposed to untrusted third party sites.

To solve this, add one of following to the embedded frame’s HTML response header:

Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp
Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: credentialless (Chrome > 96)

How do I configure the static assets served from "_app/immutable/workers" to have the Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp headers?

Current setup of vite.config.ts
const viteServerConfig = () => ({
    name: "add-headers",
    configureServer: (server) => {
        server.middlewares.use((req, res, next) => {
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy", "same-origin");
            res.setHeader("Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy", "require-corp");
            next();
        });
    },
});

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        sveltekit(),
        Icons({
            compiler: "svelte",
        }),
        viteServerConfig(),
    ],
    server: {
        open: "/",
        headers: {
            "Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy": "require-corp",
            "Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy": "same-origin",
        },
        host: '0.0.0.0',
    },
    worker: {
        format: "es",
    },
    build: {
        outDir: "dist",
        target: "ES2022"
    } 
  },


Show how you set up COEP right now.  Also specify if you have more than one HTTP server, or if everything is in one server (the one serving on port 4173).

Added snippet of my vite.config.ts. I just have 1 http server

That host specification.  Show the actual HTTP headers of the main page and the worker script.  Is it possible that one request requests to localhost, but another to say, 127.0.0.1 or something?  That would be a violation of COEP.

Request URL: http://localhost:4173/ Request Method: GET Status Code: 200 OK Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:4173 Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK Access-Control-Allow-Origin: * content-type: text/html cross-origin-embedder-policy: credentialless cross-origin-opener-policy: same-origin Content-Encoding: gzip Date: Sat, 16 Nov 2024 23:16:59 GMT Connection: keep-alive Keep-Alive: timeout=5 Transfer-Encoding: chunked

Request URL: http://localhost:4173/_app/immutable/workers/shout.wasm.worker-fuz9AyH7.js Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
Response headers:
not-set cross-origin-embedder-policy:

Origin seems ok.  Is that all you get as response headers from the worker JS request?

I believe so: https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/fUiK3TdZBmSS.png?o=1
